# Norm of an ideal is finite

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I want to show that the norm $N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\mathfrak{a})$ of $\mathfrak{a}$ a nonzero integral ideal of a number field $K$ is finite, and so $N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\mathfrak{ab})=N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\mathfrak{a})N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\mathfrak{b})$ for both $\mathfrak{a,b}$ nonzero integral ideals.

I know that the norm of a nonzero integral ideal of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is defined as the index of $\mathfrak{a}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, ie. $N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\mathfrak{a})=[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathfrak{a}]=|(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{a})|$.

I also know that, for $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K^*$, $|N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\alpha)|=[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathcal{O}_K\alpha]$ but I don't think this is very useful considering nonzero integral ideals specifically.

I'm not sure how to tackle this. I assume, once considering the definition of the norm, the problem is reduced to proving the properties for the fields $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{a})$ and $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{b})$, but how do I prove any results using them? I know that the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is finitely generated, but I'm not sure if that is useful either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the finiteness you should use that $\mathcal O_k \cong \mathbb Z^n \cong \mathfrak a$ as **abelian groups**, this implies that the quotient is finitely generated torsion group, hence finite.

For the multiplicativity you should notice that the chinese remainder theorem ensures that it suffices to show $N(\mathfrak p^n) = a^n$, when $N(\mathfrak p)=a$.

To that account consider the exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathfrak p^{n-1}/\mathfrak p^n \to \mathcal O_k/\mathfrak p^n \to \mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p^{n-1} \to 0$$

and use induction.